# How to get background image to cover entire screen when in a smaller div

Tags: css

I have a `<div class="container">` that covers 60% of the screen. How would i use background on class background and have it cover entire screen?

```
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    <div class="background">
        I want this to have background across entire page
    </div>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    <div class="background">
        I also want the background here
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .container {
        width=60%;
   }
   .background {
        background-image: url("img.jpg");
        /*???*/
    }
</style>
```

I dont want to put everything to separate divs.

Comment: What I don't understand is the logic of what you're trying to achieve. If you want the background image to cover entire screen, why not set it to body element or some page container instead of putting it on `.background` element? The second thing which doesn't make any sense is repeating that same `.background` element and basically overlapping background-images... what am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
width:60%;
}

.background {
background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
width:100vw; /* replaced with 100% */
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    <div class="background">
        I want this to have background across entire page
    </div>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    <div class="background">
        I also want the background here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "How would i use background on class background and have it cover **entire** screen?"

Comment: Sorry. Yes. Use width:100vw instead of width:100%. I have edited.